# Powershell add sitecollection primary adminstrator

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-server

I want to create PS script to create sitecollection and add the primary and secondary sitecollection administrator. However i need to find out if the user account user that used to assign in SiteCollection primary and secondary administrator not exist, how i can handle this by using the default username. Such as contoso\sp_farm. Thank you

## The first section contains the variables you need to specify based on your needs

```
$url = "http://teams.contoso.com/depts/IT"
 $ContentDatabase = "SharePoint_Content_Teams"

     # OK… the content database is not something you are able to specify

     # when creating a site collection in the user interface, but it’s so

     # important and so many people wish it were there, that I’m adding it

    # to this script
 $WebsiteName = "Information Technology"
 $WebsiteDesc = "Information Technology department team site"
 $Template = "STS#0"

     # If you don’t know the names of templates,

     # enter the command GET-SPWebTemplate

 # Information about the primary site collection administrator (Owner)

 # Note that the information should match what is in Active Directory for

 # the username, display name, and email address
 $PrimaryLogin = "CONTOSO\LolaJ"
 $PrimaryDisplay = "Jacobsen, Lola"
 $PrimaryEmail = "Lola.Jacobsen@contoso.com"

 # Information about the secondary site collection administrator (Secondary Owner)
 $SecondaryLogin = "CONTOSO\AprilM"
 $SecondaryDisplay = "Meyer, April"
 $SecondaryEmail = "April.Meyer@contoso.com"



 # Names of the default Members and Viewers groups

 # You shouldn’t have to change these unless you’re using a

 # default language other than English
 $MembersGroup = "$WebsiteName Members"
 $ViewersGroup = "Viewers"



 # Create a site collection and top level website

 # The primary and secondary site collection administrators are specified

 # In Central Administration, their e-mail addresses are looked up, but

 # in PowerShell, you have to specify them or else they end up blank
 New-SPSite -Url $url –ContentDatabase $ContentDatabase -Name $WebsiteName –Description $WebsiteDesc  -Template $Template -OwnerAlias $PrimaryLogin –OwnerEmail $PrimaryEmail -SecondaryOwnerAlias $SecondaryLogin -SecondaryEmail $SecondaryEmail



 # In the user interface, after creating a site collection, the default groups are configured

 # automatically. This is not true of the New-SPSite cmdlet, so we have to create the

 # default groups (Visitor, Members, and Owners)

 $web = Get-SPWeb $url
 $web.CreateDefaultAssociatedGroups($PrimaryLogin,$SecondaryLogin,"")



 # In the user interface, the primary and secondary site collection administrators

 # are displayed with their friendly display names as looked up in Active Directory,

 # but with PowerShell the users are added to the site collection with their

 # display name set to their user name. These lines of code update the display names.

 $PrimaryAdmin = Get-SPUser $PrimaryLogin -Web $url
 $PrimaryAdmin.Name = $PrimaryDisplay
 $PrimaryAdmin.Update()
 $SecondaryAdmin = Get-SPUser $SecondaryLogin -Web $url
 $SecondaryAdmin.Name = $SecondaryDisplay
 $SecondaryAdmin.Update()

 # Finish by disposing of the SPWeb object to be a good PowerShell citizen
 $web.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about calling [`EnsureUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.ensureuser%28v=office.14%29.aspx) to see if the user exists before you call `New-SPSite`?

```
$user = try{ $web.EnsureUser($PrimaryLogin) }catch{}
if ($user) {
    ...
}
```

Although I don't know what you would do if the user does not exists.

Comment: This will add the user to a web that he / she might not have permissions to. But if it is done on the current web, on the current user I guess it is valid

Comment: Well, the `$web` variable in OPs gist does not yet exist, so what SPWeb to use from my snippet is up to him/her :)

Comment: Off course :) Just wanted to get OP a heads up about possibly unwanted implications